# is there a way to monitor ActiveMQ Artemis queues deployed in Karaf?

Tags: apache-karaf, activemq-artemis

- Apache Karaf version: 4.1.1
- ActiveMQ Artemis version: 2.0.0

I have followed [these instructions](https://activemq.apache.org/artemis/docs/2.0.0/karaf.html) to deploy the artemis system into karaf.

I can send/retrieve messages to the Artemis queues and it's everything OK. But I was wondering if there is some command from the karaf shell which would allow me to list the queues or returning the number of messages in each one, connected clients ...

I can change the Artemis configuration through editing the artemis.xml file into the etc karaf folder, but it does not allow me to "ask" for information.

Is this possible? or maybe a workaround?. I am looking for something inside the karaf shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems karaf shell does not provide any way to monitor Artemis queue. What we can do is [install](http://hawt.io/getstarted/) hawtio on karaf and then monitor Artemis queues.